# How to identify build number of a macOS installer?

Tags: macos, build-version

Today I read:

> Apple today released an updated golden master (GM) version of macOS Sierra to developers… The new GM seed is build 16A323, while the build released last week was 16A320.

After downloading, in the Finder > Get Info of ‘Install macOS Sierra.app’ I see ‘Version: 12.0.49’ but no build number.

How to identifier the build number of a macOS installer?

My goal is to verify what installer I may be using.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most reliable way of telling the build number is to check the SystemVersion.plist file inside the installer's OS image file (and not the build number of the installer app itself).

1. Mount `/Applications/Install macOS Sierra.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg`
2. Mount `/Volumes/OS X Install ESD/BaseSystem.dmg` (hidden file)
3. Open `/Volumes/OS X Base System/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist` and examine the build number under `<key>ProductBuildVersion</key>`

Comment: yep, that's the only way.

Comment: There is no `BaseSystem.dmg` file there? Even though it's hidden, termal `ls` should be able to see it, right? https://imgur.com/6G7JfY9

Answer (score 6):

To determine the macOS Sierra GM build number use:

```
cat "/Applications/Install macOS Sierra.app/Contents/Info.plist" | grep -A 1 DTSDKBuild
```

Please apply the leading portion of the path if your *Install macOS Sierra.app* resides elsewhere.

Comment: I've seen that value be off from the installed build though...

Comment: On High Sierra.app it worked, on El Capitan.app the info.plist was empty xD

Comment: @Shayan Modify the path to the respective installer app (e.g. Install macOS Catalina.app, Install macOS Mojave.app or Install OS X El Capitan.app instead of Install macOS Sierra.app) - the build number of the macOS installer mustn't be confused with the build number of the installed base system by this installer (which usually is +2: e.g. 16A320 > 16A322). Chris.P provided the proper [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/253159/93229) to check the build number of the installed base system (which is a temporary one!). The final build number can be found in the InstallESD.dmg.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I know when you're booted from the same major version of the OS (10.12, in this case) you can open System Image Utility and select the Install Assistant from the Sources menu and it'll tell you the build number.

But, it will only show the installer (or other volumes) that it can image, which have to match the major version of the booted system. So if you're in 10.11 now and want to see the build number of a 10.12 installer that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the macOS High Sierra build number use:

1. Mount `/Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app/Contents/SharedSupport/BaseSystem.dmg`
2. Open `/Volumes/OS X Base System/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist`
3. Find the version number under `<key>ProductBuildVersion</key>`

Comment: How does this differ from [the accepted Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/253159/17907)?

Comment: It works on High Sierra. `BaseSystem.dmg` location changed

Answer (score 0):

**MOST UPDATED ANSWER for 2020.**

Since macOS Mojave, a lot of things have changed. I hope this newer answer remains valid for at least a couple of releases. I'm listing down few different methods, just in case one becomes obsolete.

Below commands assume you have already `cd` to `/Applications/Install macOS XXX.app/Contents`

1. `cat Info.plist| grep -A 1 DTPlatformVersion` should give you the full version like **<string>10.15.6</string>**
2. `cat Info.plist | grep -A 1 CFBundleShortVersionString` should give you should give you the minor version (postfix after 10.x) like **<string>15.6.00</string>**
3. `cat version.plist| grep -A 1 CFBundleShortVersionString` should give you should give you the minor version (postfix after 10.x) like **<string>15.6.00</string>**
4. `cat SharedSupport/InstallInfo.plist | grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}'` should most probably be able to give you the version in format **XX.XX.XX**

Comment: There is no need to `cat`, `grep pattern file` works better. Also `defaults read /Applications/Install macOS *.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleShortVersionString` will give you the expected result without the XML stuff.

Comment: There is no need to use **Terminal** as these files are readable in the preview pane in **Finder**.

Comment: @user3439894 I agree, however, it's much easier to provide and follow instructions that are simple to copy-paste in a terminal than laborious step-by-step guides for GUI which are error-prone.

Answer (score -2):

To find the build number once macOS Sierra is installed:

1. Choose Apple Menu > About This Mac
2. Choose System Report... to start System Information app
3. Choose Software from left side
4. From right side find "System Version: macOS 10.12 (build number here)"

Comment: This Question is about the macOS install-*er* rather than the install-*ed* macOS.